# Is it possible to swap the order of integration of the following integral with quadratic bounds, but a non-convex region of integration?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is it possible to swap the order of integration on the integral
$$
     \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-x^2-1}^{x^2+1} f(x,y) dy dx
$$
using Fubini's theorem?  More generally, the above region of integration is non-convex.  Does non-convexity cause issues when trying to swap the order of integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\chi_{+}$ be the characteristic function of $[0,\infty)$. Then you can write your integral as
$$
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{+}(x^{2}+1-y)\chi_{+}(x^{2}+1+y)f(x,y)dydx.
$$
The functions $\chi_{+}(x^{2}+1\pm y)$ are jointly measurable in $x,y$. Assuming $f$ is also jointly measure, and that the product of these is absolutely integrable, then there's no problem to write the above as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{+}(x^{2}+1-y)\chi_{+}(x^{2}+1+y)f(x,y)dxdy.
$$
The whole issue becomes finding a jointly measurable function which is 1 on the region in question and 0 otherwise.